# PHP's Simple-HTML-DOM works for one URL but not the other

Tags: php, image, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to extract the main image in a "product page" of two different Chinese shopping sites.

site 1 product-page link :
http://www.aliexpress.com/item/100FT-7-Core-Strand-550-Parachute-Cord-Nylon-Lanyard-Desert-Paracord-Survival-Kits-For-Climbing-Camping/541809415.html

Site 2 product-page link :
http://detail.china.alibaba.com/offer/1235158006.html

My code works just fine for site #1, but for site #2 i get a strangely short html string.

**Here's my code :**

```
<?php 
require_once('./includes/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');

$url="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/100FT-7-Core-Strand-550-Parachute-Cord-Nylon-Lanyard-Desert-Paracord-Survival-Kits-For-Climbing-Camping/541809415.html";
$html=file_get_html($url);

echo "html lenght : ".strlen($html)."<br>";

foreach($html->find('meta[property=og:image]') as $element) {
    echo("result : ".$element->content);
    }

echo "<br>-------------------------------------------------------------------<br>";

$url="http://detail.china.alibaba.com/offer/1235158006.html";
$html=file_get_html($url);

echo "html lenght : ".strlen($html)."<br>";

foreach($html->find('div[id=J_DetailInside]') as $element) {
    echo("result : ".$element->innertext);
    }
?>
```

I've been trying anything to get it to work properly but to no success,
ANY help would be much appreciated !

Comment: There might be malformed HTML on second site

Comment: Thank you, You both helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that second site redirects to 127.0.0.1 if it doesn't get any useragent
You have to set useragent with curl like this:

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/100FT-7-Core-Strand-550-Parachute-Cord-Nylon-Lanyard-Desert-Paracord-Survival-Kits-For-Climbing-Camping/541809415.html";
$html=file_get_html($url);

echo "html lenght : ".strlen($html)."<br>";

foreach($html->find('meta[property=og:image]') as $element) {
    echo("result : ".$element->content);
    }

echo "<br>-------------------------------------------------------------------<br>";

$url="http://detail.china.alibaba.com/offer/1235158006.html";


$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13');
$pagie = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);



$html=str_get_html($pagie);

echo "html lenght : ".strlen($html)."<br>";

foreach($html->find('div[id=J_DetailInside]') as $element) {
    echo("result : ".$element->innertext);
    }
?>
```

btw, div[id=J_DetailInside] seems to fetch too much

Comment: Thanks kitty :-) I'm going to check if that works.  Just one more questions that will help me better understand that process : How did you know that this site doesn't like my useragent and thus redirect to 127.0.0.1 ? do you use some tool for that ?

Comment: well, first i saw php warning that file_get_contents failed so I checked url with curl/wget and it seemed to be ok, so useragent or other serverside checks were most likely to be reason - i checked with telnet and realized that its useragent